# javascript map array and return object

Tags: javascript, associative-array

I have the following JSON array:

```
[
  [22, "Data Structures", 45],
  [23, "English", 52],
  [22, "English", 51],
  [26, "Data Structures", 72],
  [23, "Data Structures", 61],
  [26, "English", 81]
]
```

where each array contains an ID, subject and marks obtained.

How do I use the JavaScript `map()` function to get response as?:

```
{
  "Data Structures" : "26",
  "English" : "26"
}
```

That means it should return id of student who scored highest marks.

Comment: please add what you have tried.

Comment: do you only want to use `map` or some other will do?

Comment: we can do any other logic, I was trying to use for loop but its required two loops I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are working with arrays you can use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) if you would prefer. This solution loops over every item in the array and, depending on whether the current record is higher than the last recorded record, saves the current record to the supplied accumulator (`{}` in this case.) resulting in the following object.

```
{
  "Data Structures": { "id": 26, "score": 72 },
  "English": { "id": 26, "score": 81 }
}
```

If you want to boil it down further to just the subjects and the ID of the student who did best you can loop over the objects keys and set the value to the id.

```js
var myArray = [
    [22, "Data Structures", 45],
    [23, "English", 52],
    [22, "English", 51],
    [26, "Data Structures", 72],
    [23, "Data Structures", 61],
    [26, "English", 81]
];

var findMaxScores = function(highScores, entry) {
  var currentId = entry[0];
  var currentSubject = entry[1];
  var currentScore = entry[2];
  var record = highScores[currentSubject];

  if (record === undefined || currentScore > record.score) {
      highScores[currentSubject] = {
        id: currentId,
        score: currentScore,
      };
  }
  return highScores;
}

var highScores = myArray.reduce(findMaxScores, {});

Object.keys(highScores).forEach(subject => highScores[subject] = highScores[subject].id);

console.log(highScores);
```

Comment: Index `0` is the student ID, but the question wants the highest score (index `2`). You need to keep track of the subject and store the max, along with the ID. You are missing the step where you transform the ID/score into the ID. See: https://jsfiddle.net/cmkpqzcs/

Comment: Good catch. I was assuming the last index was an id for what ever reason

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for collecting max values and then render the object.

The first part iterates the given data and destruct the array to `id`, `subject` and `score`.

Then a check takes place, if an object exists and if so, it takes the score or zero to compare with the actual score.

If the check is `true`, set/update the map.

For getting the result, all entries are taken of the map and for each entry an object is returned with subject as key and id as value.

Later, [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) creates from many objects a single object.

```js
var array = [[22, "Data Structures", 45], [23, "English", 52], [22, "English", 51], [26, "Data Structures", 72], [23, "Data Structures", 61], [26, "English", 81]],
    map = new Map,
    result;

array.forEach(([id, subject, score]) => {
    if ((map.has(subject) && map.get(subject).score || 0) < score) {
        map.set(subject, { id, score });
    }
});

result = Object.assign(
    ...[...map.entries()].map(([subject, { id }]) => ({ [subject]: id }))
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This seems excessively complicated and does not include any explanation. The OP is likely to copy+paste this solution and never figure out how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I would sort the data first, then add the first category for each entry to a map.

```js
var scoringData = [
  [22, "Data Structures", 45],
  [23, "English", 52],
  [22, "English", 51],
  [26, "Data Structures", 72],
  [23, "Data Structures", 61],
  [26, "English", 81]
];

var sorters = [ { key : 1, dir : 1 }, { key : 2, dir : -1 } ];
console.log(retrieveHighest(scoringData, sorters, 1, 0));

function retrieveHighest(data, sorters, categoryIndex, targetIndex) {
  var sorter = multiSorter.apply(null, sorters);
  return data.sort(sorter).reduce((result, item) => {
    if (result[item[categoryIndex]] === undefined) {
      result[item[categoryIndex]] = item[targetIndex];
    }
    return result;
  }, {});
}

function multiSorter(sorters) {
  var tailArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  return function(a, b) {
    var key = typeof sorters === 'object' ? sorters.key : sorters;
    var dir = typeof sorters === 'object' ? sorters.dir : 1;
    var aV = a[key], bV = b[key];
    var equality = (typeof aV === 'string' ? aV.localeCompare(bV) : aV - bV) * dir;
    if (equality === 0 && arguments.length > 1) {
      return multiSorter.apply(null, tailArgs)(a, b);
    }
    return equality;
  };
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```